# Adding wsp:policy in wsdl programmatically

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

How do you add security policy `wsp:Policy` in `wsdl` document that I am trying to create for my SOAP web service?

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
<wsp:Policy>...</wsp:Policy>
</sp:TransportBinding>
<sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
<wsp:Policy>...</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
<sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
<wsp:Policy>...</wsp:Policy>
</sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
<sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">...</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust13 xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">...</sp:Trust13>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

I am using JAX-WS along with Spring for building the SOAP web service. Part of service is also to provide metadata which is mostly I am building by writing WSDL definition using `WSDL4J` API. Something like below:

```
    WSDLFactory wsdlFactory = WSDLFactory.newInstance();
    Definition definition = wsdlFactory.newDefinition();

    // Namespaces
    setNamespaces(definition);

    // Policy
    setPolicy(definition);

    // Messages - Input
    setInputMessageForWSDLDefinition(definition);
    // Messages - Output
    setOutputMessageForWSDLDefinition(definition);
    // PortType
    setPortTypeForWSDLDefinition(definition);
    // Binding
    setBindingForWSDLDefinition(definition);
    // Service
    setServiceForWSDLDefinition(definition, singleSignOnService);
```

Comment: Could you please add some more details. What are you using to create the service? Is this regarding a Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS) web service?

Comment: The WSDL should be an automatic result of the implementation with JAX and you should need to generate it explicitly with WSDL4J. Or am I missing the point here? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/security/tws_securitypolicy.htm

Comment: You mean - I don't have to generate it explicitly? I am building a metadata(wsdl) that can then be provided to other service providers to use the service

Comment: Check the link above, you shall be able to derive the wsdl from your implementation. It depends on what you use, but a generated wsdl shall be available at the address endpoint?wsdl automatically. Let me know and I’ll type it as a full detailed answer for other people to see in the future.

Comment: One reason why I am not using that way, is there is lot of custom validation before Token Creation process.

Comment: I ended up using apache-cxf to attach the policy dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I added policy to wsdl

```
@Policies(
{ @Policy(uri = "classpath:SecurityPolicy.xml") })
```

`apache-cxf` provides this facility to add policy to wsdl